# How can I use session entities programming with Node.js?

Tags: entity, dialogflow-es, chatbot, entities

I need to create session entities and use them in my project.
I'm using Node.js to do it, but I'm having trouble finding some code/example to take. Can you give me some?

I found this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow-enterprise/docs/reference/rest/v2/projects.agent.sessions.entityTypes), but it gives me only the JSON representation.
I need to create new session entities.

Answer (score 0):

For starters, take a look at the [nodejs-dialogflow](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-dialogflow) library. It makes some of the tasks (authentication) easier. It also includes examples for [creating session entities](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-dialogflow/blob/master/samples/resource.js#L397) and other tasks.